# Why was this math puzzle question migrated to Science Fiction & Fantasy?

Tags: bug, migration

There was a recent question on MathOverflow which was just incorrectly migrated to Science Fiction & Fantasy (where it has been promptly deleted).  I suspect the reason the question was migrated is because it contained colourful language (King Arthur, Witches, etc.).

It is debatable whether the question belonged on MathOverflow anyway (Fedor Petrov commented that it was probably more appropriate on Art of Problem Solving).  However, I am worried that future questions with colourful language might be incorrectly migrated to another Stack Exchange site.

> Is this a new feature (or bug) where questions are automatically migrated?  Or was this a moderator decision?

Comment: This is no software bug. -- I migrated the question (instead of merely closing it) because I thought Science Fiction & Fantasy may be a good place for it. Obviously, I was wrong.

Comment: I suppose that the question you mean is this one: [Minimum number of rounds?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/400764) The [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/400764/revisions) and the [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/400764/timeline) show the rejected migration.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, that is the question.  Thanks.  At the time I wrote this question, it was migated to Science Fiction & Fantasy, and I could not find a link to it on MO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no software bug. -- I migrated the question (instead of merely closing it) because I thought Science Fiction & Fantasy may be a good place for it. Obviously, I was wrong.